# Given $A, B,C$ in $P(E)$, find $X \in P(E)$ s.t. $(A \bigtriangleup B) \cup (C \bigtriangleup B) = (A \setminus B) \cup X \cup (C \setminus A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given this problem, while the point `a)` is fairly simple, requiring a lot of algebraic manipulations, how would you approach the point `b)`?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out the symmetric differences:

$$
A \bigtriangleup B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)
$$
and
$$
A \bigtriangleup C = (A \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus A)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
A \bigtriangleup B \cup A \bigtriangleup C &= (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus A) \\
&= (A \setminus B) \cup X \cup (C \setminus A)
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
X = (B \setminus A) \cup (A \setminus C) \text{.}
$$